# TextView manipulateable from thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I need help understanding View manipulation using threads. I have `TextView` whose text I would like to manipulate from a `Thread`. Here is my code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            mTextView.setText("foo");
        }
    });

thread.run();
```

What I understood initially is that views cannot be manipulated from a background thread. But this sample does indeed change the `TextView`'s text to "foo": What exactly is happening in the situation? I ran this in my Activity's onCreate method.

Does this imply that the TextView here is indeed manipulated on the UI thread ? Apologies if I have missed something very obvious.

Comment: You could use `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` to update views if you want, this gets a UI thread. I guess maybe that's whats happening with your implementation as well ??

Comment: Thank you. But what exactly is happening here ? How is the TextView manipulateable at all ? Isn't a new thread that is not the UI thread being initialized when the run method is called ? Apologies for missing something very obvious ...

Comment: So I had a look at the documentation, `Each application has at least one thread running when it is started, the main thread` Maybe this is what's happening, I'll get back to you if I find out more.

Comment: Please, check my answer and if it is helpful, accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that you start the thread in a wrong way.
You call `thread.run()` and this just executes `run()` method in UI thread.
If you want to execute a separate thread, you should call
`thread.start()`. This is how it works.

And in this case you will catch an exception of accessing UI elements outside the UI thread.

**EDIT**

Also, you probably execute your code inside `onCreate()` method.
The thread is taking very little time, so if it is inside `onCreate()` method, It finishes before the UI even appears on the screen.

If you move the code to `onResume()`, for example, and add some sleep code in your `run()` method before accessing `TextView`, like this:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

it will crash.

**EDIT2**

> Does this imply that a new thread isn't allocated from the thread pool until after a certain period of time elapses ?

No. New thread allocation is not time-dependent. 
It starts ... as soon as it has been started.
The problem is that it executes too fast.

Without loss of generality, let's proceed with `TextView` as a subject of my reasoning. `TextView` is a regular class. You create an instance of that class and use it to manipulate corresponding low-level UI element. What happens when you assign new text to your `TextView`? First, the new value is been written to it's instance field. Then, a corresponding low-level UI element is been triggered by your instance, like: "Hey, my state has been changed. Update it on the screen, please." If a screen is visible, then UI element says: "Ok, got it", takes new value and updates itself. But if the screen is not visible, it means that UI element **does not even exist yet**. There is nobody to answer and the trigger goes in vain.
Here goes the main part. All of this happens, when you call `setText()` method of a `TextView` class. But only "updating UI element"-part is forbidden to do in a non-UI thread. Accessing and changing `TextView's` instance field from a separate thread comes out perfectly legal. The thing is that you can't do one without another.

So why does it not crash in our situation?
Our thread does only one thing - text changing, thus it finishes very fast, before even `onCreate()` method returns. And because UI becomes visible only after `onResume()` method returns, your "access of UI element from a separate non-UI thread" has, actually, nothing to do with UI, because this UI does not even exist yet and, therefore no UI elements are triggered by your change. But when UI actually becomes visible, it just reads current state of the `TextView` instance - which is already changed to the new value - and updates itself, in UI thread.

Generally, even putting your thread in `onResume()` method does not guarantee that it will finish after `onResume()` method returns.
By adding `Thread.sleep(...)` method into our thread, we are just giving it some time and a chance to stay alive until `onResume()` returns, actual UI gets loaded and appears on the screen. And after that happens, the "accessing-UI-only-from-UI-thread" **RULE** enters into force and crashes the app.

Usually we don't need to artificially extend thread's life length in order to catch the crash, like in this situation, because commonly the activities or fragments we are working with, are already running for some amount of time and their UI is already visible.

So the main point is whether UI becomes visible before non-UI thread will be able to access it.

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but this is my understanding of all this.

Comment: The TextView's text can still be changed when the start() method is called.

Comment: @user1841702 did it help?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed correspondence. This answer raises another question for me. Why is the behavior time-dependent ? Does this imply that a new thread isn't allocated from the thread pool until after a certain period of time elapses ?

Comment: @user1841702 I've updated my original answer. I hope it get's more clear now.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This answered a lot of other questions I had.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

With that you can start a task that will run asynchronously but you have some methods (`onPreExecute`and `onPostExecute`) that will run in the main thread

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that you spawn a background thread which is different from the UI thread. You cannot modify Views in that thread. You will to create a handler which will send messages to the UI thread to tell it to update.

See https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html for more information

Comment: Thank you. But I still have some difficulty understanding how the TextView's text could be changed in the first place. Since I am initializing a new thread, doesn't this mean the thread in question is not the UI thread ? If that was indeed the case how was the TextView manipulatelable at all? Apologies for missing out something here...

Comment: The UI thread is the default thread that you use in your app. That's why you can modify views and why if you do heavy computation, the screen freezes. Any other thread that you create is considered a background thread. Those threads cannot modify anything that you see on the screen. So to modify a view from the background thread, you send a message to the UI thread and ask it to update.